# TypeErrorType struct Nft.MarketItem memory[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Nft.MarketItem storage ref[] storage pointer

Tags: solidity, blockchain

```
function fetchListedNFT() public returns (MarketItem [] memory){
    uint totalCount = _tokenIds.current();
    uint itemCount = 0;
    uint currentIndex = 0;
    for(uint i=0;i<itemCount;i++)
    {
        if(idMarketItem[i+1].seller == msg.sender)
        {
            itemCount++;
        } 
    }
    for(uint i=0;i<itemCount;i++)
    {
        if(idMarketItem[i+1].seller == msg.sender)
        {
            uint currentId = i+1;
            MarketItem storage currentItem = idMarketItem[currentId]; <--------- ERROR
            items[currentIndex]=currentItem;
            currentIndex++;
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

why getting this error??

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to assign a **MarketItem** struct with storage location type **memory** to a variable with storage location type **storage**. These storage location types are not implicitly convertible.

use memory like this

```
MarketItem memory currentItem = idMarketItem[currentId];
```